# Where should the callback be in fs.writefile?

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner to node.js and I have been following an online course when I received this error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined

```
fs.writeFile(fileDescriptor, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        fs.close(fileDescriptor, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                callback('false');
            } else {
                callback('Error closing existing file');
            }
        });
    } else {
        callback('Error writing to existing file');
    }
});
```

I am pretty sure that I have already included a callback here. How should I solve this?

Comment: Always read the docs when unsure: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback - in your case you didn't specify *what* you want to write to the file (which should be the second argument)

Comment: `callback` looks undefined in your code snippet, it should be a function. Probably you would like to replace the `callback` with `console.log` for the purpose of testing and learning

Comment: Also, you're using the wrong function: `fs.writeFile('filename-string.txt', data, callback)` when what you want is `fs.write(file_descriptor, data, callback)`

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing a callback function to fs.writeFile (should be the third argument) and the second argument for fs.writeFile should be the data which you want to write.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = "Text, text and more text.";

function callback(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log("File written successfully\n");
    }
}

fs.writeFile("file.txt", data, callback);
```

More info:

- callbacks: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced
- fs.writeFile: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback